# Can you match numbers using shell parameter expansion?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to remove some numbers from end of a string using parameter expansion, like:

```
 export ENV=dev12
 echo ${ENV##[0-9]+}
```

But it doesn't work and I can't find anything on google on how to do this? Anyone know?

Comment: `${var##...}` removes from the _beginning_ of the string. For removing from the end, use `${var%%...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter expansion uses glob syntax, not the more canonical regex syntax that grep and other tools use. You also have to use `%%` since `##` is for prefixes.

There's no plain glob equivalent for what you want to do, but since you're using `bash` you can can enable extglob and use `+([0-9])`:

```
shopt -s extglob
ENV=dev12
echo ${ENV%%+([0-9])}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using BASH regex you can do:

```
str='dev12'
[[ $str =~ ^(.*[^[:digit:]])[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

dev
```

Comment: I'm up voting this because it's awesome but way too much complexity for what I am trying to do, interesting answer though

Comment: It might look complicated but regex gives feature that glob (or extended glob) can never match. For example to remove a decimal number from end instead of integer cannot be solved by glob but can be easily solved using regex.

Comment: I agree that regex is very powerful, but I was able to remove decimal number using glob: `${ENV%%+([0-9]).*}` Will handle: `dev12.0` , `dev12.12345` and `12.`

Comment: But that will also change `"dev12.abc"` to `"dev"` which is not correct

Comment: Yes good point, I just need to strip env number from label, so do not have that use case, but I see what you mean